# get windows service used memory using wmi

Tags: python, wmi

I'm trying to retrieve the amount of memory used by a windows service, for example, IIS. I'm using python and windows wmi extensions. I didn't find any method on WIN32_Service class that would give me the information I need. What's the best approach to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Information concerning process memory is exposed through WMI using the [`Win32_Process` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In particular, you'd probably be interested in the `WorkingSetSize` and `VirtualSize` properties. Since you are starting from a service, you will want to obtain the `ProcessId` property from your service in order to select the appropriate Win32_Process instance.

Monitoring the total memory consumption of IIS can be a bit complex as IIS spins up multiple processes and services depending on how it's configured (see the [hierarchy of managed entities described here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732050%28WS.10%29.aspx)). But, let's assume for this example that we're only interested in the memory consumed by [W3SVC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc734944%28WS.10%29.aspx), which implements the actual HTTP protocol. Assuming we are using Tim Golden's [fantastic WMI library](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/index.html), we would need to do something like this:

```
 import wmi

 c = wmi.WMI()
 for www_srv in c.Win32_Service(Name = 'W3SVC'):
      for process in c.Win32_Process(ProcessId = www_srv.ProcessId):
          print 'Memory used by W3SVC', process.WorkingSetSize
```